# Automate module install through command line in dockerized odoo

Tags: linux, command-line, automation, docker, odoo

We are trying to automate the deployment of new custom modules in our dockerized odoo containers.

We have tried  the alternatives we found in other threads, for example:

```
odoo -i <my_module> -d test
```

And we always get the same message:

```
WARNING  test odoo.modules.loading: invalid module names, ignored:  <my_module>
```

I we try to install manually it  installs perfectly.
We also already checked that:

- The name of the module is correct.
- The **manifest**.py is correct.
- The folder of the module is in the correct path.

We are using the odoo 12 docker image.

How can we achieve the installation of modules using command line?

Is there an alternative to automate deployment of modules?

Regards.

Comment: So, what did you end up doing?